# sapply function based on colSkewness

Tags: r

I'm trying to compute the log values of a dataframe based on the Skweness values for each column. The condition is that if the Skweness is equal or higher to 2.5 then the log10 should be calculated otherwise I would like to keep the original values for that column.

I am trying to use the following line of code using the sapply command but it applies the log10 to the whole dataframe (df).

```
new_df<-as.data.frame(sapply(df, function(x) ifelse(colSkewness(df) >= 2.5, log10(x), x)))
```

Comment: Probably `colSkewness(df)` is always returning `TRUE`. Did you mean `colSkewness(x)`? Also, you want `if` not `ifelse` there, though it may not matter.

Comment: You should note that `colSkeweness` is from `fBasics`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got what you want, I'd try:

```
    indices<-which(colSkewness(df)>=2.5)
    newdf<-df
    newdf[,indices]<-log10(newdf[,indices])
```